# Twilio client chat - how to search channels by name?

Tags: javascript, twilio

How can i search channels by displayName ? I'm using Javascript SDK and trying to implement search chat history in my app but can not found the doc for it.

Comment: I assume you meant `friendlyName`? I think you want [`getPublicChannelDescriptors`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.1.2/docs/Client.html#getPublicChannelDescriptors__anchor). As far as I can see, it doesn't allow you to filter, so you'll get all the channels and will have to check the `friendlyName` client-side. The REST API *does* allow for this type of filtering, so if you have such a big list that this is too inefficient. you might have to resort to that.

Comment: yes I meant `friendlyName`, thanks @smarx. How about filtering messages by content in one channel, does REST API support ? I can not find in the REST API doc, too...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you link to the documentation you're looking at? If it's supported, it should be in the documentation.

Comment: I want to find a way to search channels by name and messages in channel by message's body. Just don't know that if twilio supported them or not, I read the doc in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest and https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.2.0/docs/index.html.

Comment: I think you're looking in the right place, and I *believe* that functionality (filter channels by their message contents) is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @smarx.

Answer (score 1):

(Twilio engineer is here). This feature is not currently supported. Meanwhile, we have it in plans for sure.

Comment: Thanks, it's great to know that, hope it'll be released soon.